# What is MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel? What is the use of that

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I am creating a video compressor using MediaCodec. In some sample code I found MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel. I didn't find the explanation of that any where on the Internet. Also my code is working without using it. So can anyone explain the importance of CodecProfileLevel?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It defines which features is used on a particular codec, max bitrate, resolution etc in case of AVC you can look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding. If you didn't define it, it will automatically choose a profile and level.